# How do I get rid of these patches from my bath tub?

Tags: bathtub, cleaning

[image]

My bathtub has these patches.
The bathtub seems to be plastic / fiberglass made.

How can I clean them?

Any idea?

Please help.

Comment: Are those on the surface? Under the surface? or coming through from the back?

Comment: What is the bathtub made of - if you knock on it with a chunk of wood, does it *gong* like metal or *thunk* like plastic?

Comment: My guess is that the tub is plastic/fiberglass.  That looks like a fairly complex shape for a cast iron tub, especially considering when such a tub would have been made.

Comment: @SteveSh Its a plastic/fiberglass.

Comment: @SolarMike It seems like it is coming from the back...I tried to scratch it but nothing happens...

Comment: How and what have you been using to clean the tub?  Some not regular tub cleaners might have eaten the top finish of the tub and stains are getting under it.

Answer (score 1):

Does a magnet stick to it?

Those sure look like rust stains. If they are rust stains coming from under the finish, you "get rid of" them with the old tub and replace that with a new tub...

Not quite sure how you'd get rust stains on a plastic/fiberglass/acrylic tub. You might try oxalic acid to get rid of them if that's what you have, though.

If they are indeed coming from the back, that may not work and you revert to the tub-replacement answer as for a steel/iron tub - or you can go the "paint the tub" route, which I consider highly likely to fail from what I have seen, but it's easier and cheaper if it works for some length of time. Maybe paint it black?

Comment: This is a plastic tub. Magnet does not stick.